# What is "electronic" in electronic codebook (ECB)?

Tags: encryption, terminology, ecb

This is an honest question regarding terminology. I believe that I understand why one mode to use a block cipher is called a codebook. But I wonder why electronic as a work appears here?

Is it fair to say this is just a fancy/stylish addition?
Should it relfect that often encyption is used with electrical devices?
Would ECB be impossible for a mechanic setup?

Answer (score 6):

In a paper codebook, plaintext words (perhaps arranged alphabetically like in a dictionary) lead to a replacement word.
[image: Codebook]
*Cipher for Telegraphic Correspondence* — a code book used by Union General Joseph Hooker’s code clerk. Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebook).

A block cipher implemented using *electronic* circuitry (as DES was initially) does the equivalent, with block instead of word, and new key instead of new book. That's thus an *electronic* codebook. The [operating mode based solely only this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) is Electronic CodeBook.

It would be possible to implement a block cipher using non-electronic means, e.g. mechanic of even manual; and operate it in ECB mode. Fact is, this was not done on a large scale. Before DES, mechanical ciphers tended to operate on a letter-by-letter basis, not something wide comparable to a word.

Comment: Would that not mean that naming it electronic simply for one possible implementations (even though a common one) is rather misleading idea? It seems at least you suggest that ECB is used as a term for somehting which could be implemented not to `electronics`-wise?

Comment: Should we include something like "keyed block cipher = permutation = codebook"?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Nobody in their right mind is going to implement a block cipher in a mechanical device, let alone calculate the output by hand. This is a rather theoretical issue. You can however e.g. implement it using a FPGA instead of a CPU, so I think that "electrical" is precisely the right term.